# updated from 14.04 to 14.10 internet is not working

Tags: updates, internet, opengl

I tried updating for the second time, worked but can't connect to my network and it can't connect to Ethernet either. When I tried opening a steam game, it have me an error.

OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.